# which app key should I set for heroku?

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, configuration, key

I am trying to deploy my laravel project on Heroku. In the deployment steps at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel , I am asked to set the **32 char** APP KEY for the application

I am really confused, that should I use the already generated APP_KEY environment variable in the .env file which is something like this: 
APP_KEY=base64:3784jZeQ333utc4G8NxL9o2v6r8ct4ffTrRzFsStHrm0=

But this string is not 32 chars long, and the example in the steps clearly shows a random 32 char string.
My env app key seems to be encryted.

I already tried using this env app key, but after deploying I get error: Whoops something went wrong.

### -Should I have to use the SAME key as generated in .env file ?

Comment: Set `$ heroku config:set APP_DEBUG=true` while deployment or change `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)` in  `config\app.php`. Then it will show the exact error rather than `Whoops something went wrong`. Please post that error output or post your stacktrace/log

Comment: @Vaibhavraj Roham I tried that, but it remains the same. Actually,  env('APP_DEBUG', true) will first check the APP_DEBUG environment variable in .env file , if it fails to find it, only then it takes the 'true' option, and my APP_DEBUG is already true in .env.

Comment: If it is true then it should show the error. Ok can you provide logs?

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham I tried getting the logs but i could not get anything substantial other than http error codes. However I have solved the problem, really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I re-deployed my application again and used the entire base64 string of the .env file APP_KEY environment variable. It works fine now.